# How to indent or center a PROC REPORT column output to RTF?

Tags: sas, rtf

This is the output that I need in RTF format:

```
**DEMOGRAPHICS A-B**
Age             
   n          18    
   Mean       30.4
   SD         6.29
   Min        18    
   Median     30.5
   Max        39
```

but I am getting this result:

```
**DEMOGRAPHICS A-B**
Age             
n         18    
Mean      30.4
SD        6.29
Min       18    
Median    30.5
Max       39
```

How do I left align **age** and center the remaining variables?

Here is my code:

```
proc report data = FINAL2  split = "@" 
 STYLE(REPORT)=[BACKGROUND=WHITE BORDERCOLOR=BLACK BORDERWIDTH=0.1 ASIS=on  FRAME=HSIDES RULES=GROUPS]
       STYLE(HEADER)=[BACKGROUND=WHITE];

    COLUMN DESC STAT1;

    define DESC / "Demographic Characteristics"  style(column)=[cellwidth=30%] style(header)=[just=left asis = on] ;
    define STAT1 /"A - B@(N=18)" style(column header)=[cellwidth = 20%] style(header)=[just = left asis = yes];
```

Comment: Can you supply an example using datalines or the sashelp library, please? Also do you have the problem when you output to html or pdf? Or is it just RTF where it is not centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a compute block to do this.  This would be executed per row but you could conditionally apply a column-specific style from there based on the variable's value being 'Age' or something else.

For example (you can add this after the `define` statements in your `report` step):

```
compute desc;
  if desc ^= 'Age' then
    call define(_COL_, "style", "style=[paddingleft=3em]");
endcomp;
```

This would apply a 3em padding to each desc column that doesn't match 'Age'.